# How to set width and text-align for button with CSS

Tags: html, css

There are my problems:

- The width's buttons are not the same as (1 & 2) in my image below.
- Shorten the distance between `Yearly`, `Monthly` and `Weekly` as (3)

Please tell me how to correct this.

[image]

**<kbd>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/huydq91/YusA3/4/)</kbd>**

---

**HTML:**

```
<!-- Make a menu with Yearly, Monthly and Weekly -->
<ul id="out_per_chart">
<li>
    <div class="yearly">
        <div class="title">2014</div>
        <div class="container1">
            <ul class="sub-menu1">
                <li class="year"><a class="_link" href="/Lists/ChartIndex.aspx?week=1&month=1&year=2014">Yearly</a>

                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="monthly">
                         <div class="title">Monthly</div>
                        <div class="container2">
                            <ul class="sub-menu2"></ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="weekly">
                        <div class="title">Weekly</div>
                        <div class="container3">
                            <ul class="sub-menu3"></ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
#out_per_chart li {
        list-style-type: none;
    }

    #out_per_chart .title {
        border: 2px solid #2676ac;
        padding: 10px 30px;
        width: 40px;
        color: #2676ac !important;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        /* added */
    }

        #out_per_chart .title:hover {
            border: 2px solid #259add;
            cursor: default !important;
            background: #259add;
            color: #FFF !important;
            -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
            -moz-border-radius: 5px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            text-decoration: none !important;
        }

    .container1 {
        position: absolute;
        padding-left: -10px;
        padding-top: -5px;
        display: none;
    }

    .container2 {
        position: absolute;
        margin-top: -15px;
        margin-left: 50px;
    }

    .container3 {
        position: absolute;
        margin-top: -15px;
        margin-left: 50px;
    }

    ._link {
        text-decoration: none;
        border: 2px solid #2676ac;
        padding: 7px 20px 7px 20px;
        width: 30px;
        color: #2676ac !important;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }

        ._link:hover {
            text-decoration: underline;
            cursor: pointer;
            border: 2px solid #259add;
            background: #259add;
            color: #FFF !important;
            -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
            -moz-border-radius: 5px;
            border-radius: 5px;
        }

    #out_per_chart li {
        width: 300px;
        height: 30px;
        margin-bottom: 25px;
    }

        #out_per_chart li.week_num, #out_per_chart li.month_num {
            margin-left: 60px;
            margin-top: -25px;
            margin-bottom: 25px;
        }

        #out_per_chart li.year {
            margin: 0 0 5px 0;
        }
```

Comment: Generally for constant width, I use width:10%/Your percentage and same goes for height property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// ok test you this css code

#out_per_chart li {
list-style-type: none;
}

#out_per_chart .title {
    border: 2px solid #2676AC;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #2676AC !important;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100px;
}

#out_per_chart .title:hover,
#out_per_chart li a:hover {
    border: 2px solid #259add;
    cursor: default !important;
    background: #259add;
    color: #FFF !important;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-decoration: none !important;
}
.sub-menu1{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
.sub-menu1 li > a{
    border: 2px solid #2676AC;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #2676AC !important;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100px;
    display:block;
}

.container1 {
    position: absolute;
    padding-left: -10px;
    padding-top: -5px;
    display: none;
    top:60px;
}

.container2 {
    left: 45px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 43px;
}

.container3 {
    position: absolute;
}

._link {
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 2px solid #2676ac;
    color: #2676ac !important;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

._link:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 2px solid #259add;
    background: #259add;
    color: #FFF !important;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

#out_per_chart li.week_num, #out_per_chart li.month_num {
    margin-left: 60px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your code. It works quite great. Could you please add comments in the part which has your additional code. Moreover, can you set the `Week 1, Week 2,... Week 48` next to the right side of the `Weekly` like the `Monthly`?

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML markup is inconsistent, which won't make things easier. The menu for the first list item goes:

`<li>` > `<a>` then the child list elements have:

`<li>` > `<div>` > `<div>` > `<ul>`

The simplest way to achieve a consistent nested list/menu is something like this:

```
<ul id="main-list">
    <li>Top level list item 1</a>
        <ul>
            <li>Second level list
                <ul>
                    <li>Third level list item</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Top level list item 2</a>
    <li>Top level list item 3</a>
</ul>
```

Each menu is a child of the parent list item. Here's a **[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/timmah/Qv8S3/3/)** of it in action. 
It also addresses the width problem you're having.

By setting the `<a>` tags in the Fiddle example as block level, you can manipulate the width. By default, `<a>` tags are an inline element, and do not respond to `width` and `height` properties unless `display:block` is assigned.

If you absolutely must have an anchor link in some list items and not in others, then you'd need to set the widths on the parent element, in this case, the `<li>`

Answer (score 1):

1. **Structure Your HTML**
   http://jsfiddle.net/ug8rU/
2. **Add your JS**
   http://jsfiddle.net/AywLf/
3. **Add your CSS**
   http://jsfiddle.net/9v7tC/

here is the full **code**:

**HTML**

```
<ul class="record">
    <li class="main-year">
        <a href="#">2014</a>
        <ul class="main-menu">
            <li class="cat-menu yearly">
                <a href="#">Yearly</a>
            </li>
            <li class="cat-menu monthly">
                <a href="#">Monthly</a>
                <ul class="menu month-menu">
                    <li class=""><a href="#">Month 1</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="#">Month 2</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="#">Month 3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="cat-menu weekly">
                <a href="#">Weekly</a>
                <ul class="menu week-menu">
                    <li class=""><a href="#">Week 1</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="#">Week 2</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="#">Week 3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.record{
    width:300px;
}

.main-year{
    width:300px;
}

.menu{
    position:relative;
    left:60px;
    top:0px;
}


.menu{
    top:-25px;
    z-index:100;
}

.record li{
    list-style:none;
    height:25px;
    margin:1px 3px;
}

.record a{
    text-decoration:none;
    border:2px solid #2676ac;
    color: #2676ac !important;
    width:90px;
    padding:2px;
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
    border-radius:5px;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.main-menu').hide();
    $('.menu').hide();

    $(".main-year").hover(function () {
        $(this).children('.main-menu').show();
    },
    function () {
         $(this).children('.main-menu').hide();
    });

    $(".monthly").hover(function () {
        $(this).children('.month-menu').show();
    },
    function () {
        $(this).children('.month-menu').hide();
    });

    $(".weekly").hover(function () {
        $(this).children('.week-menu').show();
    },
    function () {
         $(this).children('.week-menu').hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Give a class for each box and have `.class{width:"70px";margin-top:"3px";}` in your css.
you can give a percent instead of giving it in px

Comment: I don't get your meaning here!

Comment: when you create those elements by you or using jquery, set a same class name for each element which used to diplay those boxes. then in you css, set width and margin-top to that class as in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
.title
{
   width: 80px;
   text-align: center;
}
```

and the problem solved. If text doesn't align center between top and bottom you can

```
padding-top: 10px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
```

now you can see your text in center.
Sorry for bad english.